# Magento 2 Notice: Undefined index: quantity

Tags: magento2, error, stock, quantity, undefined-variable

I'm not sure if anyone can help? I've been trying to solve this problem for some time and I've narrowed it down.

I am currently having a problem when disabling a product in Magento 2.
When I disable a product I get the following error

**Notice: Undefined index: quantity in /home/customer/www/domain.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/GetProductSalableQty.php on line 83**

This when brings up the following Screenshot in Catalog view
https://pasteboard.co/Jhs7D2g.png

Link 83
https://pasteboard.co/Jhs95Pm.png

For a temporary fix, I can log in to the database and change the SKU in catalog_product_entity table. Just by adding a random number on the end.

But if I then edit the SKU and remove the random digit and enable the product this fixes the problem until I disable it again.

Tldr: When a product is disabled this shows the above error

Comment: did you try to run bin/magento indexer:reindex ?

Comment: Hi Seb, thanks for your suggestion, I've tried reindex however this doesn't work. I'm slowly running out of ideas for a fix

Comment: i would suggest you to try disable custom modules and see if this still happen

Comment: Hi Seb, sadly this didn't work either. If I can remember this problem has been happening for a while now. But I've normally managed by fixing a product one at a time. However this is now happening with 20+ products.